# Minor Log scale ticks on the X axes

Tags: plotting

I'm generating this figure for my research:

```
Plot3D[(0.14 y/(x + (y - x)*0.14))*100, {x, 1/10^10, 1/10^3}, {y, 
  1/10^9, 1/10^6}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", None}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

[image]

My question is how can I show the minor ticks on the X-axes as it shows on the Y-axes? The ticks should be in log scale. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_] = (0.14 y/(x + (y - x)*0.14))*100 // Rationalize // Simplify

(* (700 y)/(43 x + 7 y) *)
```

The easiest approach is to just reduce the range of `x` to `{x, 10^-10, 10^-4}`

```
Plot3D[f[x, y],
 {x, 10^-10, 10^-4}, {y, 10^-9, 10^-6},
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", None},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

If it is essential to display the full range of `{x, 10^-10, 10^-3}`, manually add the ticks

```
xTicks = Join[
   Outer[{#1*10^#2, ""} &, Range[10], Range[-10, -3]] // 
    Flatten[#, 1] &,
   {10^#, 
      "10"^ToString[#], {0.01`, 0.`}, {GrayLevel[0.], 
       AbsoluteThickness[0.25`]}} & /@ Range[-10, -3]];

Plot3D[f[x, y],
 {x, 10^-10, 10^-3}, {y, 10^-9, 10^-6},
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", None},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 Ticks -> {xTicks, Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution! I do need the original range, so I'll try the second approach.

Answer (score 1):

We can fully control both the tick labels and the tick marks one each axis with the `Ticks` option.  Your log scale could have 7 decades and 4 labels.  There should be a tick mark at each mantissa from 1 to 9 and each exponent from -10 to -3.  Let's define a function that gives the proper tick label and tick mark style.

The 4 labeled ticks have a mantissa *m=1* and an even exponent, *k*, so we define

```
Clear[form]
form[m_, k_] := {10^k, Superscript["10", k],
   {0.02, 0.01}, Thickness[0.0025]} /; m == 1 && EvenQ[k]
```

In the above we use `Superscript` for the label, specify the length of the ticks on each side of the axis and we make the tick mark a little thicker.

The unlabeled decades have *m=1* and odd exponents.  We use `Opacity` to control the visibility of those labels like this:

```
form[m_, k_] := {m*10^k, 
   Style[Row[{m, Superscript[" x 10", k]}], Opacity[0.5]], 
   {0.02, 0.01}} /; m == 1 && OddQ[k]
```

We specify that all other tick with a transparent label, as

```
form[m_, k_] := {m*10^k, Style[m*10^k, Opacity[0]]}
```

Now we can apply this function like this

```
xticks = Flatten[Table[form[m, k], {k, -10, -3}, {m, 1, 9}], 1];

Plot3D[(0.14 y/(x + (y - x)*0.14))*100, 
 {x, 1/10^10, 1/10^3}, {y, 1/10^9, 1/10^6}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", None}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True,
 Mesh -> {6, 3, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {Log[#1] &, Log[#2] &},
 Ticks -> {xticks, Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image]

The `Mesh` and `MeshFunctions` options are used to align the mesh to the axis tick marks.  The gray tick labels show how we could control the mantissas and exponents in the odd exponent labels if that is style we want.  Or we can turn them off by changing the opacity to zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this in such detail. It helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
p3d = Plot3D[(0.14 y/(x + (y - x)*0.14))*100, {x, 1/10^10, 
    1/10^3}, {y, 1/10^9, 1/10^6}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", None}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ImageSize -> Large];
```

We can find the tick specification underlying `p3d` in `p3d[[2]]`:

```
Ticks /. p3d[[2]]
```

> ```
>  {Quiet[Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][#1, #2, {6, 6}]] &, 
>   Quiet[Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][#1, #2, {6, 6}]] &, Automatic}
> ```

The third argument (`{6, 6}`) specifies the number of major and minor ticks in the function that generates automatic ticks (`` Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}] ``).

So we can post-process p3d to replace `{6,6}` with a number that gives a higher number of minor ticks:

```
Replace[p3d, HoldPattern[Ticks -> t_] :> Ticks -> (t /. {6, 6} -> {8, 6}), All]
```

[image]